# Why ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table (errno: 150)?

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

```
CREATE TABLE PRICING(
    CodeVillage INT,
    TypeCabin INT,
    CodeSeason CHAR(2),
    WeekPrice INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(CodeVillage, TypeCabin, CodeSeason)
);

CREATE TABLE SEASON(
    CodeSeason CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
    NameSeason VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Pricing_CodeSeason Foreign KEY (CodeSeason)
    REFERENCES PRICING(CodeSeason)
);
```

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'france.season' (errno: 150)
```

The problem is on the foreign key but why?

`PRICING` has no data in it.

Comment: 'in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the first columns in the same order. 'https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html https://dbfiddle.uk/I8KYR8VU

Comment: Re (re)search success: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 2):

A foreign key establishes a 1:n relation. The parent table has a primary key, so each row is uniquely identifyable. The child table has a foreign key referencing this primary key, so as to say which parent row a child row belongs to.

You have mistakenly tried to place the foreign key in the parent table.

```
CREATE TABLE season
(
    CodeSeason CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
    NameSeason VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE pricing
(
    CodeVillage INT,
    TypeCabin   INT,
    CodeSeason  CHAR(2),
    WeekPrice   INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(CodeVillage, TypeCabin, CodeSeason),
    CONSTRAINT Fk_CodeSeason FOREIGN KEY (CodeSeason) REFERENCES season (CodeSeason)
);
```

Comment: So, you mean that the child table should be created ahead of the parent table? Or just create the foreign key after the definition of parent table and child table in case that they both exist?

Comment: You first create the season table. Then you want a table that refers to those seasons. So, the next step is to create that table (pricing) where you have a foreign key telling the DBMS that the season that you use in that table must exist in the season table. Just as shown in my answer. The parent table is `season`. The child table is `pricing`. Each pricing belongs to a season.

Answer (score 1):

Since the error isn't really verbose, execute

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

instead, which let you know some more details under section `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR`:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2023-09-26 09:26:17 0x1910 Error in foreign key constraint of table `test_db`.`season`:
Create  table `test_db`.`season` with foreign key `Fk_Pricing_CodeSeason` constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns.
```

Comment: oh I think my sql message like this: 230926 15:37:59 Error in foreign key constraint of table france/season:
 Foreign KEY (CodeSeason)
REFERENCES PRICING(CodeSeason)
):
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.

Comment: Output is different, since I copy/pasted it from MariaDB. However the reason is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I added an index after the definition part of the `Pricing` and it works.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_CodeSeason ON PRICING (CodeSeason);
```

This is from the message in the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` part, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77177775/why-error-1005-hy000-cant-create-table-errno-150/77177839#77177839). The `CodeSeason` is on the third part of the primary key, and the SQL engine requires a first position based index or primary key or so.

Comment: Yes, I was posting the same answer but you had figured out yourself. Although there is a PK containing the referenced column, the column alone can not be used as an index due to INDEX's leftmost principle. On the other hand, had the referenced column been the first column in the composite PK, you would not have encountered the issue.

Comment: This index gets you over the error, but is this what you want? You want to be able to insert pricings with some CodeSeason ('12', 'AX', ...), and in case you insert a row in the season table, that CodeSeason must already exist in at least one row in the pricings table? That sounds like a weird construct. It would be more natural to have all allowed CodeSeason in the season table and on insert in the pricing table it is checked that the season it refers to is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error message you got already implied that you need to create an index for the referenced column: ***Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.*** You don't have to change your code, just create an index for the referenced column in the parent table before attempting to create the child table:

```
CREATE TABLE PRICING(
    CodeVillage INT,
    TypeCabin INT,
    CodeSeason CHAR(2),
    WeekPrice INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(CodeVillage, TypeCabin, CodeSeason)
);

create index idx_codeseason on PRICING(CodeSeason);

CREATE TABLE SEASON(
    CodeSeason CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
    NameSeason VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Pricing_CodeSeason Foreign KEY (CodeSeason)
    REFERENCES PRICING(CodeSeason)
);
```